# String variable are not show into subTitle

Tags: android, string

I have developed a basic app with 5 fragments. Each fragment shows a different title and only the first fragment shows also the subTitle.

This is the code:

```
switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    setTitle("fragment_0",set);
                    if(searchFragment == null) searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
                    currentFragment = searchFragment;
                    mapButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btTopQuery.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    setTitle("fragment_1",null);
                    if(queryFragment == null) queryFragment = new QueryFragment();
                    ((QueryFragment)queryFragment).viewStatus = 0;
                    currentFragment = queryFragment;
                    btTopQuery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setTitle("fragment_2",null);
                    showDownLoadDialog();
                    return;
                case 3:
                    setTitle("fragment_3",null);
                    if(newsFragment == null) newsFragment = new NewsFragment();
                    currentFragment = newsFragment;
                    CustomSharedPreferences.init(getApplicationContext());
                    CustomSharedPreferences.setPreferences(Constants.READ_NEWS_COUNT,FirstProjectApplication.allNews.size());
                    menu_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    setTitle("fragment_4",null);
                    if(infoFragment == null) infoFragment = new InfoFragment();
                    currentFragment = infoFragment;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    setTitle("fragment_5",null);
                    if(socialFragment == null) socialFragment = new SocialFragment();
                    currentFragment = socialFragment;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    setTitle("fragment_6",null);
                    if(settingsFragment == null) settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    currentFragment = settingsFragment;
                    break;
            }

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frameContainer, currentFragment)
                    .commit();
            //.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navdrawer);
        }
    });
```

and :

```
if(currentFragment == null) {
            setTitle("fragment_0",set);
            if(searchFragment == null) searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
            currentFragment = searchFragment;
            mapButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btTopQuery.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameContainer, currentFragment).commit();
        }
```

The variable `set` has a value that I read from a JSON, with this code:

```
String set;

//Reading text
            String url1 ="url_json";
            StringRequest strReq1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("", response.toString());
                    try {
                        FirstProjectApplication.allNews.clear();
                        JSONObject featureCollection=new JSONObject(response);
                        String news=featureCollection.getString("TAG");
                        set = news;
                        Log.d("test_json", news);
                        Log.d("test", "news count:"+news.length());

                        for(int i=0;i<news.length();i++) {
                            NewsResponse newsResponse = new NewsResponse();
                            FirstProjectApplication.allNews.add(newsResponse);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(menu_adapter != null) {
                        menu_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            FirstProjectApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq1, "str_req");
```

The `setTitle`method :

```
public void setTitle(String title,String subTitle) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    getActionBar().setSubtitle(subTitle);
}
```

Now in the `case 0` into `setTitle`, I set the `set` variable and it is shown correctly instead the variable `set` is not shown when is inserted into setTitle of currentFragment, but if I replace the with a hard coded string, it is displayed.

Comment: What is this `setTitle` method you are using ?

Comment: So you are saying that the subtitle is only set for the fragment number 0 ?

Comment: Yes i set the subTitle for only fragment_0 and fot the other set null vule

Comment: ok, so I think I have some trouble understanding what your problem is. Can you elaborate and post a screenshot showing your problem ?